# char array initialization with octal constant

Tags: c, octal

I saw a comment that said initialization of a char array with `"\001"` would put a nul as the first character. I have seen where `\0` does set a nul.

The unedited comment:

> char input[SIZE] = ""; is sufficient initialization. while ( '\001' == input[0]) doesn't do what you think it is doing if you have initialized input[SIZE] = "\001"; (which creates an empty-string with the nul-character as the 1st character.)

This program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 8
int main ( void) {
    char input[SIZE] = "\001";

    if ( '\001' == input[0]) {//also tried 1 == input[0]
        printf ( "octal 1\n\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ( "empty string\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

running on Linux, compiled with `gcc`, outputs:

```
octal 1
```

so the first character is `1` rather than `'\0'`.
Is this the standard behavior or just something with Linux and `gcc`? Why does it not set a nul?

Comment: I would say the referred comment is wrong.

Comment: `\0` _by itself_ produces a NUL, but the standard behavior is for `\001` to produce a character with numeric value 1, as you observed.  (The general rule is that a backslash followed by one, two, or three octal digits is a single escape.) Please quote us the _complete and unedited_ actual comment that you saw, with at least five lines of context above and below, and if possible provide a link to the entire program you are quoting.

Comment: There is a difference between `'\001'` and `"\001"`

Comment: @SaeidYazdani But it is not really relevant here

Comment: Yes there is, @SaeidYazdani, and the OP gives every indication of understanding that.

Comment: Hmm, the comment is definitely wrong for "standard" C, but the way it's written makes me wonder if there might have been pre-C89 compilers that didn't always consume three octal digits (when available) after a backslash.  I can't remember tripping over one, but I am not _quite_ old enough to have experienced the full diversity of pre-standard C.  Xing, could you please tell us where you read this comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this the standard behavior or just something with Linux and gcc? Why does it not set a nul?

The behavior of the code you present is as required by the standard.  In both string literals and integer character constants, octal escapes may contain one, two, or three digits, and the C standard specifies that

> Each octal [...] escape sequence is the longest sequence of
>   characters that can constitute the escape sequence.

([C2011, 6.4.4.4/7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p7))

In this context it is additionally relevant that `\0` is an octal escape sequence, not a special, independent code for the null character.  The wider context of the above quotation will make that clear.

In the string literal `"\001"`, the backslash is followed by three octal digits, and an octal escape can have three digits, therefore the escape sequence consists of the backslash and all three digits.  The first character of the resulting string is the one with integer value 1.

If for some reason you wanted a string literal consisting of a null character followed by the decimal digits 0 and 1, then you could either express the null with a full three-digit escape,

```
"\00001"
```

or split it up like so:

```
"\0" "01"
```

C will join adjacent string literals to produce the wanted result.

Answer (score 3):

> I saw a comment that said initialization of a char array with "\001" would put a nul as the first character.

That comment was in error.

From *6.4.4.1 Integer constants*, paragraph 3, emphasis mine:

> An octal constant consists of the preﬁx 0 *optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only*.

But what we are looking at here *is not an integer constant at all*. What we have here is, actually, an *octal escape sequence*. And that is defined as follows (in *6.4.4.4 Character constants*):

```
octal-escape-sequence:
        \ octal-digit
        \ octal-digit octal-digit
        \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
```

The definition -- both for integer constants as well as character constants -- is "greedy", as elaborated by paragraph 7:

> Each octal or hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of characters that can constitute the escape sequence.

That means, if the first octal digit is followed by something that *could* be an octal digit, that next character is *considered* an octal digit belonging to that constant (to a maximum of three in the case of character constants -- not so for integer constants!).

Hence, your `"\001"` is, indeed, a character with the value 1.

Note that, while *octal* character constants run up to three characters maximum (making such a constant quite safe to use if padded with leading zeroes as necessary to get a length of three digits), *hexadecimal* character constants run as long as there are hexadecimal digits (potentially overflowing the `char` type they are meant to initialize).

Comment: The most important part is the uncited http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p7

Comment: That's what my last paragraph is paraphrasing, yes. (I didn't want to drag the formal "leaking" spec for *hexadecimal-escape-sequence* into this.)

Comment: `The definition -- both for integer constants as well as character constants -- is "greedy"` - is this an example of [maximal munch rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: I am actually not sure if the C syntax definition *as a whole* is meant to be greedy; in the places I am aware of it making a difference, it's made explicit in the surrounding text.

Answer (score 2):

See http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.4.4.html

Octal sequence is defined as:

```
  octal-escape-sequence:
            \ octal-digit
            \ octal-digit octal-digit
            \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
```

and item 873:

> The octal digits that follow the backslash in an octal escape sequence
>   are taken to be part of the construction of a single character for an
>   integer character constant or of a single wide character for a wide
>   character constant.

also item 877:

> Each octal or hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of
>   characters that can constitute the escape sequence.

Therefore the behaviour is correct. "\001" should not have null byte at position 0.